# Using SciPy to interpolate data into a quadratic fit

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, data-analysis

I have a set of data that when plotted most points congregate to the left of the x axis:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker='o')
plt.title('Original')
plt.show()
```

[ORIGINAL GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcalM.png)

I want to use scipy to interpolate the data and later try to fit a **quadratic line** to the data. I am **avoiding** to simply fit a quadratic curve **without interpolation** since this will make the obtained curve *biased towards the mass of data at one extreme end of the x axis*. I tried this by using

```
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')

# Array with points in between min(x) and max(x) for interpolation
x_interp = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=np.size(x))

# Plot graph with interpolation
plt.plot(x_interp, f(x_interp), marker='o')
plt.title('Interpolated')
plt.show()
```

and got [INTERPOLATED GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WdUX.png).

However, what I intend to get is something like this:
[EXPECTED GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NgB2.png)

What am I doing wrong?

My values for x can be found [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1520097369651.txt) and values for y [here](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1520096335678.txt).
Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to interpolate, that is something entirely different.  You likely want to fit a quadratic function to the data.  Check out `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

Comment: sorry i just reuploaded my x values

Comment: I need to interpolate because if I fit a curve without interpolation, the curve will be biased towards the data that congregates around one end of the x axis and will not accurately reflect the trend.

Comment: @GuoJiachen, I don't think that would be the case.  See solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

I'm *pretty sure* this does what you want. It fits a second degree (quadratic) polynomial to your data, then plots that function on an evenly spaced array of x values ranging from the minimum to the maximum of your original x data.

```
new_x = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=np.size(x))
coefs = np.polyfit(x,y,2)
new_line = np.polyval(coefs, new_x)
```

Plotting it returns:

```
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.scatter(new_x,new_line,c='g', marker='^', s=5)
plt.xlim(min(x)-0.00001,max(x)+0.00001)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: interpolated data]

## if that wasn't what you meant...

However, from your question, it seems like you might be trying to force all your original y-values onto evenly spaced x-values (if that's not your intention, let me know, and I'll just delete this part).

This is also possible, there are lots of ways to do this, but I've done it here in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
xy_df=pd.DataFrame({'x_orig': x, 'y_orig': y})
sorted_x_y=xy_df.sort_values('x_orig')
sorted_x_y['new_x'] = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), np.size(x))

plt.figure(figsize=[5,5])
plt.scatter(sorted_x_y['new_x'], sorted_x_y['y_orig'])
plt.xlim(min(x)-0.00001,max(x)+0.00001)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Which looks pretty different from your original data... which is why I think it might not be exactly what you're looking for.

[image: weird interpolation]